# Tell R to use string stored in object as column name

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am trying the following:

```
a <- "b"
data.frame (a = c (1:3))
```

which returns (of course):

```
data.frame (a = c (1:3))
>   a
> 1 1
> 2 2
> 3 3
```

What I want is:

```
a <- "b"    
data.frame (foo (a) = c (1:3))
>   b
> 1 1
> 2 2
> 3 3
```

Is there a way to tell R to use the string (`"b"`) stored in an object (`a`) as column name?

EDIT: I know that the title of my question is perhaps not very meaningful. Are there suggestions for improvement?

Comment: `df <- data.frame (a = c (1:3)); names(df) <- a`

Comment: also an elegant solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `setNames`

```
setNames(data.frame(1:3), a)

#  b
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
```

Or using `matrix` and adding `dimnames`

```
data.frame(matrix(1:3, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `tibble` and evaluate (`!!`) the object on the lhs of `:=`

```
tibble(!! a := 1:3)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#      b
#  <int>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
```

---

We can also use `set_names` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(1:3) %>%
     set_names(a)
```